# Appcelerator How to use socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, appcelerator-alloy

I'm working on an app in Appcelerator, using alloy. I want to use socket.io in my application in order to receive live data from an API.

I've never used socket before. So, I just want to know how to include socket.io.

I've tried installing the socket.io through npm command. And also included a socket.io.js file.

But when I use `var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);` I'm unable to get the socket library.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK! I did what I wanted using webView. Included the socket.io script and it worked like charm.

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [tiws](https://github.com/omorandi/tiws) (iOS/Android) for creating native websockets, without WebViews.